# How to load strings with DataTable.Load() not as numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio

I have the following code:

```csharp
System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            System.Data.DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables.Add("Utilizatori");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = Globals.Sheet13.Range["A7", "D12"];
            Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject listObject = Globals.Sheet13.Controls.AddListObject(range, "Utilizatori");

            try
            {
                dataTable.Clear();
                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = mySqlConnection;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, telefon, e_mail, worksheet_name, adresa, nume FROM consumatori";
                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    
                    dataTable.Load(reader, System.Data.LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
                    listObject.AutoSetDataBoundColumnHeaders = true;
                    listObject.SetDataBinding(ds, "Utilizatori");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
```

From the field "telefon" I would like to retrieve the numbers with starting 0s in the numbers.
For now, my Excel table brings in the "**0**7xxxxxxxx" string as a number like 7xxxxxxxx. I can't figure this one out, the load method converts it into a number, or does the Excel Sheet formatting converts the string into a number?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Aren't you looking at speeds going down with usage of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` If you use large files, try out `Sylvan`, just few second needed to extract few thousand rows. 

If you still got a problem with reformatting value from '0789' to 789, then you could write extension method for `DataTable`, where you pass coulmn name, or index, number of needed length and add 0 until it's fixed.

Comment: @KrzysiekMastalerz Thanks for the advice! How do you write an extension method for DataTable? Can you point to a link please?

Comment: Create a new static class, for excample: https://gist.github.com/KMastalerz/871daf1de2127d00c8bb1957ff5dfbad
To add to that sylvan, although limited to reading is fast and free to use unlike Epplus or Aspose. Yes those all great libraries, but for just reading Sylvan gets better benchmarks and like i said, it's free.

Comment: Here is excample of usage of Sylvan & Extension
https://gist.github.com/KMastalerz/fcaecd54c2790646c13b3fe459ac5d7d 
i wrote it quickly (the extension) so let me know if you need anything.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Excel Sheet was the one to blame. I was pulling in numbers, starting with 0, and he formatted them to numbers.

```csharp
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListColumn column in listObject.ListColumns)
                    {
                        column.Range.Cells.NumberFormat = "@";
                    }
```

By setting the formatting to text it shows up correctly.

Comment: Hi Bogdan - Daniel Mihalcea, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)